# Elastic Search Unassigned Shards

Tags: elasticsearch

my cluster state was green and after restart of service one shard remains UNASSIGNED and status goes to yellow. I have 2 machines with 5 shard and 1 replica set settings. I am using default config with multicast off and uni cast enabled.I did rerouting using

```
for shard in $(curl -XGET http://localhost:9201/_cat/shards | grep UNASSIGNED | awk '{print $2}'); do
    echo "processing $shard"
    curl -XPOST 'localhost:9201/_cluster/reroute' -d '{
        "commands" : [ {
              "allocate" : {
                  "index" : "wall", 
                  "shard" : '$shard', 
                  "node" : "node1", 
                  "allow_primary" : false
              }
            }
        ]
    }'
    sleep 5
done
```

Which gives following output

```
{
"acknowledged":true,
"state":{
  "version":48,
  "master_node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
  "blocks":{

  },
  "nodes":{
     "EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ":{
        "name":"node2",
        "transport_address":"inet[/XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:9300]",
        "attributes":{

        }
     },
     "Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA":{
        "name":"node1",
        "transport_address":"inet[/XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:9301]",
        "attributes":{

        }
     }
  },
  "routing_table":{
     "indices":{
        "wall":{
           "shards":{
              "2":[
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":false,
                    "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":2,
                    "index":"wall"
                 },
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":true,
                    "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":2,
                    "index":"wall"
                 }
              ],
              "0":[
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":true,
                    "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":0,
                    "index":"wall"
                 },
                 {
                    "state":"INITIALIZING",
                    "primary":false,
                    "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":0,
                    "index":"wall"
                 }
              ],
              "3":[
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":false,
                    "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":3,
                    "index":"wall"
                 },
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":true,
                    "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":3,
                    "index":"wall"
                 }
              ],
              "1":[
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":false,
                    "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":1,
                    "index":"wall"
                 },
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":true,
                    "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":1,
                    "index":"wall"
                 }
              ],
              "4":[
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":false,
                    "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":4,
                    "index":"wall"
                 },
                 {
                    "state":"STARTED",
                    "primary":true,
                    "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
                    "relocating_node":null,
                    "shard":4,
                    "index":"wall"
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "routing_nodes":{
     "unassigned":[

     ],
     "nodes":{
        "EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ":[
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":false,
              "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":2,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":true,
              "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":0,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":false,
              "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":3,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":false,
              "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":1,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":false,
              "node":"EtQ9mOrLQbiUbHGqeQgMvQ",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":4,
              "index":"wall"
           }
        ],
        "Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA":[
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":true,
              "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":2,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"INITIALIZING",
              "primary":false,
              "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":0,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":true,
              "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":3,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":true,
              "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":1,
              "index":"wall"
           },
           {
              "state":"STARTED",
              "primary":true,
              "node":"Ar7UpWUQSpSlYcje-u6bgA",
              "relocating_node":null,
              "shard":4,
              "index":"wall"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  "allocations":[]
  }
}
```

But 0th shard is still unassigned and status is yellow.

Thanks

Comment: You ES_HEAP_SIZE is rather large for the amount of RAM you have. It's generally recommended to leave half of the RAM for the FS cache in the ES guides. You might also like to install kopf plugin

Comment: Yes i have elastic search head plugin installed to see elastic clusture.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the logs you may notice a problem, such as a lack of disk space.

You can reduce the replica count to 0 for that index and then back to 1.

Another great thing to do is to adjust the replication speed, as by default it is quite slow.